# Chaining of Promises via #flatMap() in Play Controller-Action

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, promise, nonblocking

I'd like to ask if what I'm doing is suitable or if there is a better/more efficient/simpler way.

**Scenario:**

1. User logs in with e-mail-address and password, gets routed to the login()-action
2. If the user is already in the DB and has a password hashed, authenticate with the DB-user and return result-promise
3. If user is not in the DB or has no password-hash, do a web-service request with the login-data and parse the status from the response -> return a `Status`-instance
4. Check the status of the user and return a result-promise

**Code:**

```
public Promise<Result> login() {
    Promise<User> userPromise = Promise.promise(() -> User.findByName(login.emailAddress));
    return userPromise.flatMap(user -> {
        if (user != null && user.hasPassword()) {
            if (user.authenticate(login.password)) {
                return Promise.pure(ok("login successful")));
            }
            // password did not match
            return Promise.pure(unauthorized());
        }

        // user has no password-hash stored, so do a webservice-request instead
        final WSRequestHolder holderWithParams =
                getWSRequestHolderForUserStatus(login.emailAddress, login.password);

        final Promise<Status> statusPromise =
                holderWithParams.get().flatMap(this::parseStatusFromResponse);

        return statusPromise.flatMap(status -> {
            if (status != null) {
                if (status.isValid()) {
                    return Promise.pure(ok("login successful")));
                }
                // not a valid status, return unauthorized
                return Promise.pure(unauthorized());
            }
            return Promise.pure(badRequest("response parsing error");
        });
    });
}
```

**My questions:**

1. Am I doing anything wrong or unnecessary, and if yes: what is the correct, easier or more efficient way?
2. Did I understand the use of Promises and flatMaps, am I using it correctly or "over-using" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.flatMap` is for when some return value of the function you give to it returns a `Promise` itself. If all you do is return non-futures, then you can just use `.map`, so the last `.flatMap` does not seem to need be a `.flatMap` since you just wrap all the results values in `Promise.pure`, with `.map` you can just return those values without further boxing them in a Promise.

The function you give to `userPromise.flatMap` on the other hand will return a `Promise` so it must be a flatMap or else it in turn will return `Promise<Promise<Result>>` which you cannot return from your controller action.

Comment: Basically everything you see is part of the function I give to `userPromise.flatMap`, so I'm afraid the last `.flatMap` cannot be a map, or else the return-types don't match. BUT: is the `flatMap` on my `holderWithParams.get()` necessary for using the `Status` as a result, or could that just be a `map`? That's the part where I'm not quite sure, I thought it has to be a flatMap because of the flattening to a single Promise for the `Status`.

Comment: To simplify my question: is the return-type (`Promise<A>` vs. `A`) the only difference between `flatMap` and `map`? If so I could indeed spare the last `flatMaps`, I thought it's necessary if I want to re-use the returned object because of the "flattening" (whatever that exactly means).

Comment: Yes that is correct, map on a Promise<A> takes a function that goes from A to B and returns a Promise<B> while flatMap takes a function that goes from A to Promise<B> and returns that Promise<B>

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying, I'm accepting this answer then because I wasn't sure if there are other implications with flatMap if I just have single objects as the type (no collections).