# Play Framework 2.4 Sequential run of multiple Promises

Tags: akka, playframework-2.4

I have got a Play 2.4 (Java-based) application with some background Akka tasks implemented as functions returning Promise.

- Task1 downloads bank statements via bank Rest API.
- Task2 processes the statements and pairs them with customers.
- Task3 does some other processing.

Task2 cannot run before Task1 finishes its work. Task3 cannot run before Task2. I was trying to run them through sequence of `Promise.map()` like this:

```
protected F.Promise run() throws WebServiceException {
        return bankAPI.downloadBankStatements().map(
                result -> bankProc.processBankStatements().map(
                        _result -> accounting.checkCustomersBalance()));
}
```

I was under an impression, that first map will wait until Task1 is done and then it will call Task2 and so on. When I look into application (tasks are writing some debug info into log) I can see, that tasks are running in parallel.

I was also trying to use `Promise.flatMap()` and `Promise.sequence()` with no luck. Tasks are always running in parallel.

I know that Play is non-blocking application in nature, but in this situation I really need to do things in right order.

Is there any general practice on how to run multiple Promises in selected order?

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting the second call to `map`, which means what's happening here is

1. processBankStatements
2. checkCustomerBalance
3. downloadBankStatements

Instead, you need to chain them:

```
protected F.Promise run() throws WebServiceException {
    return bankAPI.downloadBankStatements()
                  .map(statements -> bankProc.processBankStatements())
                  .map(processedStatements -> accounting.checkCustomersBalance());
}
```

I notice you're not using `result` or `_result` (which I've renamed for clarity) - is that intentional?

Comment: Well, I am using `F.Promise.promise(lambda)` which is returned by `processBankStatements` and `checkCustomerBalance`. Promises cannot have void result type so I am returning null from promise. So the results are irrelevant. All three functions/promises are doing some database jobs and they do not return anything. The only purpose is to run these jobs in selected order. I am aware that this is not a good approach and good use of Play features, but in this case it is needed. Anyway thanks for advice. I will try.

Comment: It's no problem whatsoever if the return value isn't needed, I was just checking the answer was complete.

Comment: Well, it is not working. Now all three promises starts in parallel.

Comment: How do you know? Logging, or something else? I suggest using breakpoints within the lambdas to determine execution order.

Comment: I am seeing this in log. Also it is visible in data processing. For example, on the first run, 10 bank statements are downloaded, 0 is processed (should be 10). On next run more 20 bank statements are downloaded, 10 is processed. Next run 5 is downloaded, 20 is processed. It seems that once promise number 2 is run, it cannot see new recent bank statements because they are not present in database in that time. Instead it sees items from previous downloads. In log, I see start of all three tasks at the same time and various end times depending on task duration.

Comment: That sounds more like like a cross-thread visibility/transaction issue, which is outside the scope of the question.  You would be better adding a new question to address this.

Comment: Right, I will check the breakpoints you suggested. Anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I found a solution. The correct answer is:

If you are chaining multiple Promises in the way I do. That means, in return of `map()` function you are expecting another `Promise.map()` function and so on, you should follow these rules:

- If you are returning non-futures from mapping, just use `map()`
- If you are returning more futures from mapping, you should use `flatMap()`

The correct code snippet for my case is then:

```
return bankAPI.downloadBankStatements().flatMap(result -> {
        return bankProc.processBankStatements().flatMap(_result -> {
            return accounting.checkCustomersBalance().map(__result -> {
                return null;
            });
        });
});
```

This solution was suggested to me a long time ago, but it was not working at first. The problem was, that I had a hidden `Promise.map()` inside function `downloadBankStatements()` so the chain of flatMaps was broken in this case.

Comment: Inspiration of this answer came from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554687/chaining-of-promises-via-flatmap-in-play-controller-action)